# React Hook "React.useEffect" is called conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a hook inside my component, which detects when I am scrolling down or up.
This is the code :

```
const [scrollDirection, setScrollDirection] = React.useState('')
    const [prevOffset, setPrevOffset] = React.useState(0)
    const {width} = useWindowSize()
    const useScrollDirection = () => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

        const toggleScrollDirection = () => {
           let scrollY = window.scrollY
           if (scrollY === 0) {
               setScrollDirection('')
           }
           if (scrollY > prevOffset) {
               nav?.classList.remove('activee')
           } else if (scrollY < prevOffset) {
            nav?.classList.add('activee')
           }
           setPrevOffset(scrollY)
        }
        React.useEffect(() => {
            window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleScrollDirection)
            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener("scroll", toggleScrollDirection)
            }
        })
        return scrollDirection
    }
    }
    React.useEffect(() =>
    {
        
        if(width<600) {
            setMobile(true)
        }
        else setMobile(false)
    }, [width])

    useScrollDirection()
```

Eventually when I try to build the site, I get an error " React Hook "React.useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks".
I wonder why is this happening ? any idea to fix this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty self descriptive:

```
React Hook "React.useEffect" is called conditionally.
React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.
Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?
```

Documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

`useEffect` cannot be called within a function that is declared within a component. `useEffect` and other hooks must always be called in the exact same order every time a function is executed.

For your `useScrollDirection` function, you are declaring a hook (which is fine) but then you are using `useEffect` within the hook. The declaration of `useScrollDirection` must be moved to be outside of the component in order to use `useEffect` inside of it.

```js
const useScrollDirection = () => {
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    // ...
  }, []);
};

const Component = () => {
  useScrollDirection();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think about this ! Thanks .

Comment: React Hook "React.useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?

Comment: Why I am still getting the same issue ?

Comment: From your original code, the `useEffect` is within an `if` statement - `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {`. The `useEffect` hook must not be called from within an `if` statement.

Comment: I fixed this issue by exporting the `useScrollDirection` function from an independent file.